# Compare first column in each of two Excel sheets and update the differences to a text file

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

We want to compare the output of the first column in two different Excel sheets and update the differences to a text file. This is comparing only A1 data in excel1 with A1 data of excel2 and appending to the text file:

```
Dim objExcel,ObjWorkbook,objsheet,ObjWorkbook1,objsheet1,Originalvalue,filesys, filetxt

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8 

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test\copy.xlsx")
set objsheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set objWorkbook1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test\Original.xlsx")
set objsheet1 = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Originalvalue = objsheet.Cells(1,1).value

Copyvalue = objsheet1.Cells(1,1).value

If Originalvalue = Copyvalue then

Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("D:\Test\output.txt", ForAppending, True) 
filetxt.WriteLine(Originalvalue) 
filetxt.Close

msgbox Originalvalue

else 

Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("D:\Test\output.txt", ForAppending, True) 
filetxt.WriteLine(Copyvalue) 
filetxt.Close

msgbox Copyvalue

End If

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Workbooks.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
```

How can this be done for *all* the data in the A column please?

Comment: do both files have the same number of records? And you do realize that this is just going to output a txt copy of your "Copy" file right? both branches of the IF statement will write the value of Copyvalue to the txt file. Is that really the behaviour you want?

Comment: No both the files won't have the same number of records.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.. That (Copyvalue) is not required. The output text file should contain only the difference values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compares the files and if there is a different value in the copy file it is placed into the text file..if the values are equal, they are ignored..not sure if thats the behavior you are looking for, but you can at least see how to loop through the files to compare all the records

```
Dim objExcel, ObjWorkbook, objsheet, ObjWorkbook1, objsheet1, Originalvalue, filesys, filetxt
Dim objsheet_LastRow As Long, objsheet1_LastRow, LastRow As Long, RowCounter As Long, CopyValue

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

'are you doing this because you are running this outside of excel?
'if not then this doesn't have to look as complicated as it is

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set ObjWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test\copy.xlsx")
Set objsheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set ObjWorkbook1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test\Original.xlsx")
Set objsheet1 = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("D:\Test\output.txt", ForAppending, True)

'find the last row of data in each sheet, this will only go the end of the shorter file
objsheet_LastRow = objsheet.Cells(100000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
objsheet1_LastRow = objsheet1.Cells(100000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(objsheet_LastRow, objsheet1_LastRow)

For RowCounter = 1 To LastRow
    Originalvalue = objsheet.Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value
    CopyValue = objsheet1.Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value
    'if values are different, put the new value in a txt file
    If Originalvalue <> CopyValue Then filetxt.WriteLine (CopyValue)
Next RowCounter

filetxt.Close
ObjWorkbook.Close False
ObjWorkbook1.Close False
'objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
'objExcel.Workbooks.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
```

TODO: error trapping

Comment: Thanks. Error handled in for & if loops and for declaration of variables using DIM, but can't win over the error thrown for line 19 which says  Unknown runtime error. Kindly help.